i cannot import FormsModule in task.component.ts file under task folder in angular 18.0.4
i cannot import FormsModule in task.component.ts file under task folder .Due to unable to solve error as "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.ngtsc(-998002)" .My code is
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newTask.description">
in task.component.html file.Pls help to resolve this error.


If task component is standalone, add FormsModule to the imports array.
@Component({
    standalone: true,
    imports: [
      ...
      FormsModule,
      ...
    ],
    ...
})
export class TaskComponent {
    ...

If the task is not standalone, go to the place where you delared the component declarations array. Then import FormModule.
@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [
      ...
      FormsModule,
      ...
    ]
    ...
})
export class SomeModule {}


import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
selector: 'app-task',
standalone: true,
imports: [CommonModule,FormsModule],
templateUrl: './task.component.html',
styleUrl: './task.component.css'
})                                                                                                                            After typing above import FormsModule, "new dependencies optimized: @angular/forms   "messange showing in VS code, Issue has been resolved.Thanks .
